# how to save photo from image view to gallerry android xamarin

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code, xamarin.android, android-studio-3.0

hello i'm newbie in xamarin ,I try to find a lot code of internet but it won't work.

In my imageview have dot menu, When user click on menu in imageview they can forword photo or share photo but can't save.

I want to add save photo function in there , but no idea , This is part of my code to share and forward

```
public async void OnSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View itemView, int position, string itemString)
    {
        try
        {
            if (itemString == GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_MessageInfo))
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MessageInfoActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("UserId", Id);
                intent.PutExtra("MainChatColor", !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MesData.ChatColor) ? MesData.ChatColor : AppSettings.MainColor ?? AppSettings.MainColor);
                intent.PutExtra("SelectedItem", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MesData));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (itemString == GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_Forward))
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForwardMessagesActivity));
                intent.PutExtra("SelectedItem", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MesData));
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (itemString == GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_Share))
            {
                string urlImage = MediaFile;
                var fileName = urlImage?.Split('/').Last();

                await ShareFileImplementation.ShareRemoteFile(urlImage, urlImage, fileName, GetText(Resource.String.Lbl_SendTo));
            }
            
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Methods.DisplayReportResultTrack(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code used to work before `Android10.0(Android Q)` .

```
//get the data 
ImageView image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.Drawable).Bitmap;
MemoryStream baos = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, baos);
imageInByte = baos.ToArray();

//store it in gallery
Java.IO.File storagePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(storagePath.ToString(), "abc.png");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, imageInByte);
var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path)));
this.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

However , `GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated from `Android Q` ,It seems that since `Android 11` we can't write file into public external storage including gallery , it is only allowed to place file in app's own isolated shared storage.

Refer to docs :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String).